# Quota cost for LiveBroadcast.insert and LiveStream.insert and LiveBroadcast.transition?

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api, quota, youtube-livestreaming-api

These (in the title) are common operations when using *YouTube Live Streaming API*.

The daily quota limit is usually 10,000. And uploading a video (Video.insert) is already 1,600 quota points.

My question is whether this value is close in the case of dealing with **LiveBroadcast**, **LiveStream** objects and the various operations performed on them, such as **updating**, **inserting**, **binding** and **transitioning**.

I read [YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) and they say:

> YouTube Live Streaming API methods are, technically, part of the YouTube Data API, and calls to those methods also incur quota costs. **As such, API methods for live streaming are also listed in the table.**

I cannot see them on the table.

Any idea where are those equivalences between *YouTube Data API* and *YouTube Live Streaming API*?

Edit: Bug Report on Google is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186302489

Comment: This is a known documentation issue with the Youtube API, I suggest you post this documentation issue in the official [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Thanks @ZackyTalib this is the link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186302489